Botón de app en shiny genera error de closure
He hecho una app en shiny. Es una app para gestión de una clínica nutricionista. He puesto un botón para actualizar la bbdd de pacientes cada vez que llegue un paciente nuevo. Pero cuando le doy al botón, se cierra la app y aparece el siguiente error:
Warning in is.na(x) :                                                                                                                                           
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  1: runApp

Lo curioso es que la base de datos sí se actualiza con el nuevo paciente introducido. El botón lanza un mensaje de error cuando no se han introducido todos los datos, así se obliga a que se haga esto. Para comprobar esto, generé un código en el que aparecían diversos is.na(). Pero como me salía este error, probé diversas alternativas. Pero ninguna me ha resuelto el problema. El error que comento arriba sigue apareciendo.
A continuación dejo el código de la parte del botón, por si vosotros veis algo que yo no.
Algunas consideraciones:

pacientes_reactivo() convierte en reactivo un dataframe que se carga antes del inicio de la app.
datos_pacientes() captura los datos introducidos en la app, así, hago una llamada a este reactivo cada vez que lo necesito en la app, y no tengo que volver a capturar todos los datos, cada vez.

Gracias.
### para saber si están todos los datos del paciente recogidos
pacientes_ok <- reactive({
    var1 <- input$nombre2
    var2 <- input$apellido1
    var3 <- input$apellido2
    var4 <- input$fecha2
    var5 <- input$sexo1
    var6 <- input$altura1
    var7 <- input$peso2
    var8 <- input$otros1
    var9 <- input$deporte1
    var10 <- input$objetivo1
    
    var1 <- ifelse(var1 == "", NA, var1)
    var2 <- ifelse(var2 == "", NA, var2)
    var3 <- ifelse(var3 == "", NA, var3)
    var4 <- ifelse(var4 == Sys.Date(), NA, var4)
    var5 <- ifelse(is.null(var5), NA, var5)
    var8 <- ifelse(var8 == "", NA, var8)
    var9 <- ifelse(var9 == "", NA, var9)
    var10 <- ifelse(var10 == "", NA, var10)
    
    var_todos <- c(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10)
    var_todos <- complete.cases(var_todos)
    var_todos <- all(var_todos)
    var_todos
})

### funcionamiento del botón GUARDAR
observeEvent(input$guardar2, {
    if(pacientes_ok() == TRUE){
        df1 <- pacientes_reactivo()
        df2 <- datos_pacientes()
        
        df1 <- rbind(df1, df2)
        
        write_csv2(df1, "pacientes.csv")
        
        pacientes_reactivo(df1)
        
        nombres_reactivo(df1$nombre_car)
        
        updateSelectInput(session, "nombre1", choices = sort(nombres_reactivo))
    }else{
        showModal(
            modalDialog(
                title = tags$div(style = "color: red;", "Error"),
                tags$b(p("Por favor, rellena todos los campos antes de guardar."),
                       p("Clica fuera de esta ventana para cerrarla.")),
                easyClose = TRUE,
                footer = NULL
            )
        )
    }
})


Como no había forma de encontrar el error, decidí rehacer la app del todo, comprobando sección por sección dónde fallaba. EN la app completa hay algún fallo más, pero todos son por causas similares. En el código en cuestión que comparto antes, el error está en:
updateSelectInput(session, "nombre1", choices = sort(nombres_reactivo))

que debería ser
updateSelectInput(session, "nombre1", choices = sort(nombres_reactivo()))

No obstante, he añadido alguna línea más por manías mías. Vuelvo a compartir la sección que he modificado al completo:
### funcionamiento del botón GUARDAR
observeEvent(input$guardar2, {
    if(pacientes_ok() == TRUE){
        df1 <- pacientes_reactivo()
        df2 <- datos_pacientes()
        
        df1 <- rbind(df1, df2)
        
        write_csv2(df1, "pacientes.csv")
        
        pacientes_reactivo(df1)

        nombres <- df1$nombre_car
        
        nombres_reactivo(nombres)
        
        updateSelectInput(session, "nombre1", choices = sort(nombres_reactivo()))
    }else{
        showModal(
            modalDialog(
                title = tags$div(style = "color: red;", "Error"),
                tags$b(p("Por favor, rellena todos los campos antes de guardar."),
                       p("Clica fuera de esta ventana para cerrarla.")),
                easyClose = TRUE,
                footer = NULL
            )
        )
    }
})

Gracias.
